# Загрузка изображений для vk.com через api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl

Необходимо загрузить изображение для Товаров в Вконтакте. Получаю адрес для загрузки методом https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveMarketPhoto.
После, код ниже должен загрузить изображение, но получаю ошибку `ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_IMAGE_SIZE: market photo min size 400x400` Изображение разумеется больше 400x400.

```
$file["file"] = file_get_contents($image_path);
$ch = curl_init($urlUpload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$upload_data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Ответ

```
Array
(
    [error] => ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_IMAGE_SIZE: market photo min size 400x400
    [bwact] => do_add
    [server] => 638423
    [_sig] => 488b98bab6f2b936b568101b1997cb83
)
```

Comment: и? вы загружали картинки по необходимым минимум размерам?

Comment: Да, разумеется.

Comment: получается даже после загрузки файла который больше 400x400 у вас опять та же ошибка ?

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: а вы пробовали разные картинки? (VK API иногда глючит)

Comment: Да, пробовал несколько. Думаю проблема всё же в коде. Если у меня изменить поле "file" на произвольное, ошибка не изменится. Но из документации _Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте, сформировав POST-запрос с полем file._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Работающий код:

```
$image_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/temp.jpg';
$cfile = curl_file_create($image_path,'image/jpeg','temp.jpg');
$ch = curl_init($urlImage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file" => $cfile));
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
```